# Can I make a shortcut to open a new note in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, batch, shortcuts

I'm looking for a command-line style way of opening a new note in Outlook 2007.

It'll be executed from a `.bat` script.

Basically, is there some switch on `outlook.exe` or similar that I can use to get a new note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Office command line switch reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP012185891033.aspx):

> /c messageclass
>
> Creates a new item of the specified
>   message class (Outlook forms or any
>   other valid MAPI form).
>
> Examples:
>
> - /c ipm.activity creates a Journal entry
> - /c ipm.appointment creates an appointment
> - /c ipm.contact creates a contact
> - /c ipm.note creates an e-mail message
> - /c **ipm.stickynote creates a note**
> - /c ipm.task creates a task

So this should do the trick

```
\Path\to\outlook.exe /c ipm.stickynote
```